# Searching in FQL query returns only few results instead of 400~

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I did this query: `SELECT id, username, name, pic_square FROM profile WHERE contains('Restaurants in Vilnius, Lithuania')`, as a result I got only 23 results. Hovewer if I search for `Restaurants in Vilnius, Lithuania` search box, in facebook, I get around 200-400 results. Why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook limits the API result to 25 items max and you need to use paging to get the next batch: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

You really shouldn´t use FQL anymore, it will be gone for good after August 2016. Always use the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Comment: as i said, Facebook limits the result to 25 max - and forget about FQL, it´s deprecated and extremely buggy.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I made the same query with graph, but results seems same: `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DRestaurants%20in%20Vilnius%2C%20Lithuania%26type%3Dpage%26fields%3Dname&version=v2.2`

Comment: check out the first link in my answer. you need to implement paging.

Comment: I made offset based search, but results are the same...
this is how my query looks: `search?fields=name&limit=20&offset=20&type=page&q=Restaurants%20in%20vilnius%2C%20lithuania&__after_id=enc_Aex8o7WxgwTZ4F88YIbGKN0DMAvAyGIbyy1G44HZNAFiOb-7deAqz2JvWLJ3uDiRDwasv44mMTyJdW16TLVa-sfO`

Comment: i said paging, not offset...again, take a look at the first link in my answer.

Comment: @luschn FQL will be around until August 7th 2016 BTW: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: oh, my bad, thanx for the info! well, that´s still a long time, but i´d not use FQL anyway. it´s buggy, you don´t get support, and it´s deprecated.

Comment: @luschn Hi, info you provided didn't helped me. Did you meant what I should go through the pages to see another piece of information ? I red info you provided but it doesn't seemed useful to me. 
I search through Graph API Explorer. So I guess I should see here all information, also I see pagination, but other pages are empty. Could paginagation help here?

If I search same info through facebook search as user, I get much more results.

Comment: you have to use pagination if you want to get more entries, yes. check out the links i posted.